# Selecting the Next or Previous div.tablecolor jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a calendar that has all the tables wrapped in class="tablecolor" I would like to have a previous / next next to each month for the corresponding months. Here is a snippet of my html:

```
<a href="#" class="previousMonth">&laquo; Previous Month</a>
<h2 id="oct2014">October 2014</h2>
<a href="#" class="nextMonth">Next Month &raquo;</a>
<div class="tablecolor" style="width:100%;">
  <table summary="2014 Grants Calendar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
        <th scope="col">Monday</th>
        <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
        <th scope="col">Friday</th>
        <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div>1</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>2</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>3</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>4</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>5</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>6</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>7</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>8</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>9</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>10</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>11</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>12</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>13</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>14</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>15</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>16</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>17</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>18</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>19</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>20</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>21</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>22</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>23</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>24</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>25</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>26</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>27</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>28</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>29</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>30</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>31</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<a href="#" class="previousMonth">&laquo; Previous Month</a>
<h2 id="nov2014">November 2014</h2>
<a href="#" class="nextMonth">Next Month &raquo;</a>
<div class="tablecolor" style="width:100%;">
  <table summary="2014 Grants Calendar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
        <th scope="col">Monday</th>
        <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
        <th scope="col">Friday</th>
        <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div>1</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>2</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>3</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>4</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>5</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>6</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>7</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>8</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>9</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>10</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>11</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>12</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>13</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>14</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>15</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>16</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>17</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>18</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>19</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>20</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>21</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>22</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>23</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>24</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>25</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>26</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>27</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>28</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>29</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>30</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<a href="#" class="previousMonth">&laquo; Back a Month</a>
<h2 id="dec2014">December 2014</h2>
<div class="tablecolor" style="width:100%;">
  <table summary="2014 Grants Calendar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
        <th scope="col">Monday</th>
        <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
        <th scope="col">Friday</th>
        <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div>1</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>2</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>3</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>4</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>5</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>6</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>7</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>8</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>9</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>10</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>11</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>12</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>13</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>14</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>15</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>16</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>17</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>18</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>19</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>20</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>21</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>22</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>23</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>24</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>25</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>26</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>27</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>28</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>29</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>30</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><div>31</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have been attempting to get this working with the next() and prev() selectors in jQuery, but am not getting the outcome I thought I would.

```
$(".nextMonth").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextselector = $('div.tablecolor').next();
    $(window).scrollTop(nextselector.position().top);
});
$(".previousMonth").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var prevselector = $('div.tablecolor').prev();
    $(window).scrollTop(prevselector.position().top);
});
```

When I click on the Oct 2014 Next, I get the Nov 2014, but when I click on Nov 2014 next, I get nothing. Where am I missing this .next() issue?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `$('div.tablecolor').next()` try `$(this).next()`

Comment: @CDspace Man... I had done that a different way and it wasn't working. Good call. Make it the answer and I'll give you the POINTS! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$('div.tablecolor')` will always start at the first one on the page. so using `.next()` will always give you the second month. Try using `$(this).next()` and `.prev()` to reference from the link clicked.

**EDIT**
I just tried this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ67e/) and it's not quite working like you want. It should be enough to get you in the right direction. Perhaps wrap each month in another div and use `$(this).parent().next()`

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Svr7L/1/). Wrap each month, links and all, in a div, and the parent() reference works.

Comment: @jasonflaherty sorry, link got messed up, second fiddle is correct now

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
$(".nextMonth").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    var nextselector = $('div.tablecolor').eq(count);
    $(window).scrollTop(nextselector.position().top);
});

$(".previousMonth").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count--;
    if(count){
        var prevselector = $('div.tablecolor').eq(count);
        $(window).scrollTop(prevselector.position().top);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the $('div.tablecolor') is selecting the first instance of this in your page, so it will always scroll to the second $('div.tablecolor') in your page.